# How to combine Flux and ResponseEntity in Spring Webflux controllers

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I use `Mono`s with `ResponseEntity`s in my Webflux controllers in order to manipulate headers and other response info. For example:

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
fun getOneUser(@PathVariable userId: UserId): Mono<ResponseEntity<UserDto>> {
    return repository.findById(userId)
        .map(User::asDto)
        .map { ResponseEntity.ok(it) }
        .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
}

@GetMapping
fun getAllUsers(): Flux<UserDto> {
    return repository.findAllActive().map(User::asDto)
}
```

both works fine but there are cases where it is required to have `ResponseEntity` in conjunction with `Flux` as well. What should the response type be? Is it correct to use `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`?

For example:

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}/options")
fun getAllUserOptions(@PathVariable userId: UserId): ??? {
    return repository.findById(userId)
        .flatMapIterable{ it.options }
        .map { OptionDto.from(it) }
        // if findById -> empty Mono then:
        //   return ResponseEntity.notFound().build() ?
        // else:
        //   return the result of `.map { OptionDto.from(it) }` ?
}
```

The behaviour I'd like to achieve here is that getAllUserOptions returns `404` if `repository.findById(userId)` is an empty `Mono`, otherwise return `user.options` as `Flux`.

Update:
repository here is `ReactiveCrudRepository`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `switchIfEmpty` to throw an exception in case the user doesn't exist:

```
return repository
    .findById(userId)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(NotFoundException("User not found")))
    .flatMapIterable{ it.options }
    .map { OptionDto.from(it) }
```

Then with an [exception handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) translate it to a 404 response.

Comment: It won't. I'm using `ReactiveCrudRepository`.

Comment: @ovnia Just use `swithchIfEmpty`. I'll update the answer

Comment: I don't wanna have an exception here, but 404 Response. It's not an exception, but an indication the resource requested is not there. Building exception handler for such a simple case looks overkill.

Comment: This is an exceptional situation - client tries to fetch a subresource of a non-existent resource (precondition for an operation is not met). This solution is the cleanest I know and the only one you'll get at this level AFAIK. Other possible solutions step a bit lower to routing and generic ServerRequest/ServerResponse.

Answer (score 4):

You can use by returning Mono with ResponseEntity

like this

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> oneRawImage(
        @PathVariable String filename) {
        // tag::try-catch[]
        return imageService.findOneImage(filename)
            .map(resource -> {
                try {
                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                        .body(new InputStreamResource(
                            resource.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                        .body("Couldn't find " + filename +
                            " => " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });         
    }
```

I have also example like this

```
  public ResponseEntity<Mono<?>>  newLive(@Valid @RequestBody Life life) {
        Mono<Life> savedLive = liveRepository.save(life);
        if (savedLive != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(savedLive, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Mono.just(new Life()), HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
    }
```

I dislike functional programming in the REST controllers.

Here is an example [ReactiveController](https://github.com/armdev/reactive-dev/blob/master/sp33/src/main/java/io/project/app/ReactiveController.java) .

Comment: I have seen both Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> as well as ResponseEntity<Mono<T>> being used. For example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-404 they use the latter. Do you know whether there's any difference between the two functionally? Or so they both result in the same response to a client?

Comment: Author explicitly asked about Flux<?> mentioning that Mono<?> works fine.

Answer (score -1):

works for me, let me know if you have a trouble

```
@PostMapping(value = "/bizagi/sendmsg")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> sendMessageToQueue(@RequestBody BizagiPost bizagiPost) {
    Mono<BodyReturn> retorno = useCase.saveMsg(bizagiPost);
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    return retorno.map(t ->
    {
        if (t.getStatusCode().equals("200")) {
            response.put("message", t.getReazon());
            return new ResponseEntity(t, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            response.put("message", t.getReazon());
            return new ResponseEntity(t, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
```