# How to wrap Flux<T> in ResponseEntity (ResponseEntity<Flux<T>)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, flux, reactor

First of all, I know that there are a few other questions essentially asking the same thing ([How to Wrap Flux in a ResponseEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743663/how-to-wrap-fluxmyobject-in-a-responseentity), [How to combine Flux and ResponseEntity in Spring Webflux controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491405/how-to-combine-flux-and-responseentity-in-spring-webflux-controllers)), but the answers somehow all ended up returning `Mono<ResponseEntity>` in the end.

### `ResponseEntity<Mono<T>>`

Given a `Mono<Customer> getCustomer(Long customerId)` method in a `CustomersService`, my controller code would look something like this:

```java
@Autowired CustomersService customersService;

public Mono<ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomer(Long customerId) {
  return customersService
    .getCustomer(customerId)
    .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
    .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
}
```

### `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>`

Now if the service would be changed to `Flux<Customer> getCustomers(String name)` instead and the controller return type would be `ResponseEntity<Flux<Customer>>`, how should the controller code look like?

```java
public Flux<ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomers(String name) {
  return customersService
    .getCustomers(name)
    ...?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be the same as your first case.

```
@Autowired 
CustomersService customersService;

public Flux<ResponseEntity<Customer>> getCustomers(String name) {
    return customersService.getCustomers(name)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
}
```

Comment: That would have been my assumption as well, but I get a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flux<Object> to ResponseEntity<Flux<Customer>>` from my IDE. Gradle build also fails with
`incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V,T#2 exist so that Flux<V> conforms to ResponseEntity<Flux<Customer>>`